# CASE statement in SELECT in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've the following statement:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN account_id IS NOT NULL 
          THEN value 
          ELSE value_2 
    END AS result
```

How can I use 'result' in select statment?

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN account_id IS NOT NULL 
          THEN value 
          ELSE value_2 
    END AS result,
    result as result_2
```

This code doesn't work

Comment: you either need subquery, or repeatign the whole case statement for result2

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a column alias on the same level where you define it. You have to use a derived table:

```
select result, 
       result as result_2, 
       ... other columns ...
from (
  select CASE WHEN account_id IS NOT NULL THEN value ELSE value_2 END AS result, 
         .... other columns ...
  from ...
  where ...
) t
```

where re